# Pass a generic class as an input to an Akka Streams Flow

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I would like to pass a generic class as shown in the code below but I'm getting an exception:

```
Incompatible equality constraint `Pair<A, B>` and `Pair`.
```

How can I correct it? Or is there another approach?

NOTE: `Flow.of(Pair<A, B>.class)` does not work. How do I pass `Pair<A, B>` instead of `Pair`?

```
Flow<Pair<A, B>, B, NotUsed> func() {
  return Flow.of(Pair.class).map(i ->
    {
      B obj = i.second();
      return obj;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way around for simple cases:

```
  <A, B> Flow<Pair<A, B>, B, NotUsed> func(){
    return Flow.fromFunction(Pair::second);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the create() method, and use the type parameter as:

```
Flow.<Pair<A, B>>create().map(// your lambda function)
```